# Ember sortBy on property:desc is not the same as reverse

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In Ember 2, I tried `sortBy` on an Enumerable.

The `sortBy('something:asc')` works correct. But `sortBy('something:desc')` is not the same as `sortBy('something:asc').reverse()`. ( Is it not `desc`?)

I tried to change `something` property to boolean or string or number. It seems only "string" type works with `reverse`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, the [Ember.Enumerable.sortBy](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_sortBy) method doesn't take any direction, as seen [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.8.2/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/enumerable.js#L1059), that's how [Ember.computed.sort](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_sort) works, as seen in the docs example as well as when following internal calls to [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.8.2/packages/ember-runtime/lib/computed/reduce_computed_macros.js#L734).

This means that in your code `"asc"` doesn't work either. You're just getting the correct result by chance. [Relevant github issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/13822)

Additionally, the reason only strings work as arguments to `sortBy` is because `sortBy` [internally calls](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.8.2/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/enumerable.js#L1065) [Ember.get](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_get) on each element to extract a property by the name you provided, and property names are strings.

In other words, the signature for `sortBy` is `sortBy(property)` ([docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_sortBy))

The way `sortBy` determines the order of elements is by calling the [compare](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.8.2/packages/ember-runtime/lib/compare.js#L81) method from ember-runtime which, unfortunately, is an internal operation and there's no API to affect it.

Here's how to do sort in both directions properly:

- ascending: `sortBy('something')`
- descending: `sortBy('something').reverse()` (unfortunately)

I believe this is intentional since Ember follows the [convention over configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) paradigm, basically forcing you to favor usage of `Ember.computed.sort`, especially if performance is important.

```
sortingBy: ['something:desc'],
sortedCollection: Ember.computed.sort('collection', 'sortingBy')
```

Another workaround you could do is to convert the Enumerable to a regular JS array using the [toArray](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_toArray) method, sort it, and then overwrite the property with the newly sorted array:

```
const sortedDesc = this.get('something')
  .toArray() // convert the enumerable to a regular JS array
  .sort(/* your descending sort comparison function */);

this.set('something', sortedDesc);
```

And this will be faster (no need to reverse an array), but will be more memory intensive since it creates a new array (by calling `toArray`) each time you sort.

Comment: No problem mate, glad to help out :)